# how to implement read more button in every post of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on the site http://www.nickthepromisering.com/

Now friends my question is ***how to limit the Number of words in the wordpress post by adding a read more button.*** so that only some words are displayed and then when clicked on read more button the remaining post is displayed. I mean is there is any plugin for that?

Comment: where is the_content located in the theme folder?

Comment: Why not just using the 'more' button from the editor? Or does this have to work automatically?

Comment: This have to work automatically

Answer (score 1):

To only show a portion of a post's content, change `the_content();` with `the_excerpt();` in your theme.

Then, add read more links like this: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>`

Comment: where is the_content located in the theme folder?

Comment: It will be in multiple locations, depending on your theme. Check `index.php`, `archive.php`, and `category.php` for sure. Do a sitewide search in your text editor, and you probably want to replace `the_content();` everywhere except for `page.php` and `single.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo implode (" ", array_slice (explode (" ", strip_tags($post->post_content)), 300));
echo '<a href="' .the_permalink() .'">Read more</a>';
```

Please note, that this will also remove the HTML, otherwise you might end up with half open tags..